# Incluir angular.js usando maven em projeto Java Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, maven

Estou estudando o Framework Spring com Maven, na parte de inserir dependências estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade ao tentar inserir o angular.js no html da página, no arquivo pom.xml, a dependência do angularjs ficou assim:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Ai não da nenhum tipo de erro, então acho que esta certo.

No html tento inserir assim:

```
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/META-INF/resources/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"/>

</head>
```

Minha duvida principal é aonde fica o Angularjs que é incluído no projeto pelo Maven e como coloco o caminho para o js na página ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo a documentação (http://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc), você deveria botar essa tag no arquivo de configuração do spring:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Comment: Criei o projeto usando o Spring Tool Suite, a IDE criou alguns arquivos xml, fui testando em cada um deles até que deu certo no servlet-context.xml !

Obrigado!